# Css class above header or below footer

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

If you scroll through a page in jqm you can see a a border in a different color at the end or at the beginning of the page to notice the user that this is the end of the page (Above Header or Below Footer). You can see this effect only on a mobile device.
Which is the css class to change that color?

Comment: `.ui-body` maybe? [This resource](http://api.jquerymobile.com/classes/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to debug this issue is to open up your website in Internet Explorer, hit F12 for developer tools, navigate to the bottom tab of developer tools and change 'Browser Profile' to 'Windows Phone'. From here, you can right click on the area you are referring to and click 'Inspect Element' to see which classes are being applied to area and where the color is being set.

On my site it is being set in the jquery mobile min.css file on class .ui-bar-a